# How to collapse rows in dataframe by similar columns

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to collapse the following:

```
        Date  Category   input1     input2
   2019-11-08    1         NaN  182.420781
   2019-12-09    1         NaN  174.251870
   2020-01-08    1         NaN  186.296325
   2019-11-08    1  177.670203         NaN
   2019-12-09    1  177.001475         NaN
   2020-01-08    1  179.940017         NaN
   2019-11-08    2         NaN   84.369389
   2019-12-09    2         NaN   87.882385
   2020-01-08    2         NaN   86.309750
   2019-11-08    2   83.995045         NaN
   2019-12-09    2   86.166011         NaN
   2020-01-08    2   89.449188         NaN
   2019-11-08    3         NaN   83.878360
   2019-12-09    3         NaN   90.910188
   2020-01-08    3         NaN   93.120330
   2019-11-08    3   84.010900         NaN
   2019-12-09    3   86.916081         NaN
   2020-01-08    3   91.620387         NaN
```

into:

```
          Date Category    input1      input2
   2019-11-08    1         177.670203  182.420781
   2019-12-09    1         177.001475  174.251870
   2020-01-08    1         179.940017  186.296325
   2019-11-08    2         83.995045   84.369389
   2019-12-09    2         86.166011   87.882385
   2020-01-08    2         89.449188   86.309750
   2019-11-08    3         84.010900   83.878360
   2019-12-09    3         86.916081   90.910188
   2020-01-08    3         91.620387   93.120330
```

I've tried looking to `agg`, `join`, etc but I simply don't have enough knowledge to do what I need. Essentially, the inputs are repeated by `Date` and `Category`, so I would just like to collapse them all into the same respective rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us try `groupby` with `first` : it will return first not null value

```
s = df.groupby(['Category','Date'],as_index=False).first()
s
   Category        Date      input1      input2
0         1  2019-11-08  177.670203  182.420781
1         1  2019-12-09  177.001475  174.251870
2         1  2020-01-08  179.940017  186.296325
3         2  2019-11-08   83.995045   84.369389
4         2  2019-12-09   86.166011   87.882385
5         2  2020-01-08   89.449188   86.309750
6         3  2019-11-08   84.010900   83.878360
7         3  2019-12-09   86.916081   90.910188
8         3  2020-01-08   91.620387   93.120330
```